# Strange behaviour of MSI installer on uninstall package

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I made something wrong in my installer, but I don't know what it is:

- during **uninstallation** I see how all contents of the product folder is disappearing...
- ...and then, after uninstallation is complete, the contents is appearing again - my product is **not uninstalled** actually.

Such behaviour is not always, but happens accidentally (or I didn't catch some factors).

Can anybody help with this issue?

I have checked in the EventViewer that **uninstallation completed with error 1603**.
The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372835(v=vs.85).aspx) tells that this error means:

> A system restart may be required because the file being updated is also currently in use.

But no product's files were opened during uninstallation. Also I stopped all applications from my product.

Comment: I tried Microsoft Fix It utility - it didn't help. My package can't be uninstalled. The same error 1603.

Answer (score 0):

The reason became simple. In the InstallExecute sequence I had:

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
   <Custom Action="ModifyServiceConfig" Before="InstallFinalize"/>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

As a result, on uninstallation this custom action was calling too, and I got an error 1603.

I didn't considered the fact that instructions inside InstallExecute sequence are called during uninstallation too.
The fragment above must look like this:

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
   <Custom Action="ModifyServiceConfig" Before="InstallFinalize">NOT Installed</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

That means that this custom action must be called only during installation.

Comment: How about a repair or a re-install? Should the custom action be called?  If yes, the above condition should be modified to something like  NOT REMOVE. Also, as a general thumb rule, it is recommended to condition custom action on feature/component states as its possible that a msi package might have multiple features and the custom action might be applicable to just one feature, not the entire product as a whole.

Comment: Thanks, I missed this moment.